# Configuring nginx to handle PHP files and another case

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have a script that is being access via a URL like this:

```
/directory/file.php/methodName
```

I need nginx to handle this specific route and send it to PHP. Right now my config currently just catches anything ending in .php and sends it to PHP. How can I tweak my config to handle the case above as well?

Here is my nginx block:

```
# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fastcgi_split_pathinfo will not do anything, cause the location does not contain a slash and is anchored at the match end. Use a location like this:

```
 location ~ \.php/ {
     fastcgi_split_pathinfo ^(.*\.php)(/.*)$;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    ....
}
```